# How to do a join bewteen tables with a conditional statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.  I do not have a direct field to join.  But, what I want to do, is to take everything in Table1, and join it with a field that is "in" a field in Table2.  I know this will result in multiple connections between rows in Table2 to Table1, but that is okay.  Let me give a for instance..

Please have some patience.  I know there is a way to make a query to do this, but I have not done that before.  But, I can give sample data, and what I want to do with it.

```
Table1(SN, Customer)
Table2(SNRange, OrderNum, Line Item)

Table1[12, Bob,
       13, Bob,
       14, Bob,
       54, Bill,
       55, Bruno,
       56, Bruno,
       100, Sylvia]
Table2[12,13, WO234, 1,
       14, WO234, 2,
       54, WO300, 1,
       55,56, WO532, 1]

Result:(SN, Customer, WONum, LineNum)
      [12, Bob, WO234, 1,
       13, Bob, WO234, 1,
       14, Bob, WO234, 2,
       54, Bill, WO300, 1,
       55, Bruno, WO532, 1,
       56, Bruno, WO532, 2,
       100, Sylvia, NULL, NULL]
```

My very uneducated guess would be:

```
SELECT *
From Table1
INNER JOIN SN ON Table1.SN in Table2.SNRange
```

I think this defines the situation, and loose logic on how to do it.  I need some format help. SNRange is a string with commas separating the numbers.  I know my formatting is horrible, but I'm not very deep in SQL, but I have needed to do some complex things.

Thank you!!
Rod

Comment: You have to normalize your data. It's asking for nothing but trouble, as you can see trying to write your query, by having more than one value in a column.

Comment: Having multiple values munged in a single column like this is a big problem; You either have to break the values out first into individual rows before joining, or you have to join based on string-parsing; either way, the optimizer will not be able to optimally use an index and will scan all rows. You need to fix your design.

Comment: This is a one-off situation.  Its two data tables I'm given.  I need to merge them once, then I ditch the other tables.  Its not my design.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two different ways to do this, but one is more accurate than the other.

I've set up a test using the following SQL script:

```
--Build temp tables
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #table1;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table2') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #table2;

    CREATE TABLE #table1 (SN varchar(10), Customer varchar(50));
    CREATE TABLE #table2 (SNRange varchar(20), OrderNum varchar(10), LineItem int);


--Insert values into tables
    INSERT INTO #table1 (SN, Customer)
    VALUES (12, 'Bob'),
        ('13', 'Bob'),
        ('14', 'Bob'),
        ('54', 'Bill'),
        ('55', 'Bruno'),
        ('56', 'Bruno'),
        ('100', 'Sylvia');

    INSERT INTO #table2 (SNRange, OrderNum, LineItem)
    VALUES ('12,13', 'WO234', '1'),
        ('14', 'WO234', '2'),
        ('54', 'WO300', '1'),
        ('55,56', 'WO532', '1');


--View data in tables
    SELECT *
    FROM #table1;

    SELECT *
    FROM #table2;
```

**Version 1 (Accurate depending on Range values)**

```
SELECT one.SN, one.Customer, two.OrderNum As WONum, two.LineItem As LineNum
FROM #table1 one
LEFT JOIN #table2 two ON CHARINDEX(one.SN, two.SNRange)>0;
```

This returns:
| SN  | Customer | WONum | LineNum |
| :-- | :------- | :-----| :------ |
| 12  | Bob      | WO234 | 1       |
| 13  | Bob      | WO234 | 1       |
| 14  | Bob      | WO234 | 2       |
| 54  | Bill     | WO300 | 1       |
| 55  | Bruno    | WO532 | 1       |
| 56  | Bruno    | WO532 | 1       |
| 100 | Sylvia   | NULL  | NULL    |

The `CHARINDEX(one.SN, two.SNRange)` function determines if the value of `one.SN` is contained anywhere inside the value of `two.SNRange`. If it does exist, the function returns the integer value representing position of `one.SN` in `two.SNRange`. Otherwise it returns 0.

*When will this query return INACCURATE results?* Based on the values you have now, this query works. However, if you have values 1 & 12 in the Range column, this will not work because this is not matching the value of `one.SN` to a whole number in `two.SNRange`. In other words, all of these will return a value greater than 0:

```
CHARINDEX('1','1') = 1        --Good match
CHARINDEX('1','12') = 1       --Bad match
CHARINDEX('1', '201') = 3     --Bad match
CHARINDEX('1', '2,201') = 5   --Bad match
```

**Version 2 (always accurate)**

```
WITH
    cteTable2 AS
    (
        SELECT value As SN, t.OrderNum As WONum, t.LineItem As LineNum
        FROM #table2 t
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.SNRange,',') s
    )

SELECT *
FROM #table1 one
LEFT JOIN cteTable2 two ON one.SN=two.SN
```

Inside the with statement, the `STRING_SPLIT` function is key. When you have a field that contains values separated by a delimiter, this function takes those values, splits them by the delimiter, & puts each individual value into its own row.

So,
| SNRange |
| :------ |
| 55, 56  |

becomes
| SN |
| :- |
| 55 |
| 56 |

Based on the current values, the query above returns the same results as Version 1. However, if you have SN values like '1' & '101', you will not have the matching problem described in Version 1.

I hope this helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

@XMarksTheSpot

I defintely went with v2.  I did have some thoughts about a false match, but was going to handle that in a subsequent step.  Well, I did use this method.  However, when I run it, its like it doesnt know what to do with the string_split() command.  It does do a auto-match for the command, but then thows an 'Invalid object name' error.  What gives?

```html
With cteTemporary_assign_wo as
(
select value as SN, t.OrderNumber As WONum, t.LineNumber as LineNum
From dbo.temporary_assign_wo As t
cross apply string_split(t.SN_List,',') s
)


Select *
from dbo.SN_Test_DF_Idx_2 one
Left join cteTemporary_assign_wo two on one.SN=two.SN
```

The error I get:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'string_split'.